# How to put items into DynamoDB table using lambda(node.js)?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I have deployed API Gateway, Lambda and DynamoDB using SAM. The code for the lambda function is given below-

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');


exports.handler = async (event) => {
    try {
        
        console.log(event);         //To check if there is any problem with the API call or not, (CloudWatch result = No issues)
        console.log(event.body);    // To confirm if the 'event' is a JSON object or not. (CloudWatch result = No issues)
        var obj = JSON.parse(event.body);
        
        console.log(obj.id);
        console.log(obj.name);
        
        var ID = obj.id;
        var NAME = obj.name;
        
        var ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});
        
        var params = {
            TableName: 'tabmine',
            Item: {
                 id : {S: ID},
                 name : {S: NAME}
            }
        };
        
        ddb.putItem(params, function(err,data){
            if(err){
                console.log("Error: ", err);
            }
            else
            {
                console.log("Item entered successfully:", data);
            }
        });
        
        var response = {
                'statusCode': 200,
                'body': JSON.stringify({
                    message: 'Data entered successfully'
            })
        };
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return err;
    }

    return response;
};
```

Using Curl, I ran the following command to enter the datas mentioned in the request body.

```
 curl -X POST -d '{"id":"1","name":"sam"}' https://0000000000.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/Prod/writedb
```

It ran successfully. But when I checked the DynamoDB table, no data was present.

Then I checked the CloudWatch logs, I found no errors.
But as per my lambda code, if a new item is successfully entered in the DynamoDB table, then `console.log("Item entered successfully:", data);` should get executed and I should get the output in the CloudWatch. But I have not got any output.

From the above scenario, I came to a conclusion that in the lambda function code, following statements are not getting executed.

```
 ddb.putItem(params, function(err,data){
            if(err){
                console.log("Error: ", err);
            }
            else
            {
                console.log("Item entered successfully:", data);
            }
        });
```

I am not able to figure out, why this portion of code is not getting executed. Please help.

Comment: You're using asynchronous JavaScript. Your Lambda function exits before the DynamoDB call completes so your callback never happens. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/using-promises.html

Comment: Yes that solved the problem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nothing is printing because the asynchronous lambda code completes before the call to `putItem` does it's job.

You should convert the `putItem` call to `promise` and `await` for it's response.  It would look something like this

```
try{
    const data = await ddb.putItem(params).promise();
    console.log("Item entered successfully:", data);
} catch(err){
    console.log("Error: ", err);
}
```